# Debug Step into local Nuget Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Warning, wall of text ahead. tl;dr I can step into a local nuget package on my computer I developed, coworkers can't. help?

I developed a nuget package on my main dev machine and pushed it to our local nuget server. I was surprised to find on my computer, I am able to step into the nuget package once referenced in other projects. My coworkers (and my other PC) are not able to step into the nuget package. I've done a lot of searching and people referncing things like setting up a symbol server or pulling pdb files etc. I'm not opposed to doing that, BUT, I didn't do any of that on my main machine where I can step into the nuget package. Literally the only thing I did is build / compile the nuget pkg and push it to the server and then open another instance of Visual Studio with a differnet project and I can step in. Can anyone help fiure out why I can step in and others can't?

Comment: just for your information: I tried to do this and the only option which I found was to use ReSharper which is not free(but it can decompile dll on fly)

Comment: @Selvin That's just it though, I'm using 100% out of the box visual studio 2017 pro, and I *can* step into and debug the nuget package. I didn't configure or do anything different. Can't figure out how that's working

Comment: Did you tried to `nuget pack –symbols` ? it should create Project.1.0.0.0.symbols.nupkg

Comment: I don't know? I ran this to publish the package. `dotnet nuget push GenRepo.1.0.10.nupkg -s http://10.10.10.30/nuget` and it's just worked on my main pc. I don't understand how.

Comment: `dotnet pack  --include-symbols` or `dotnet push --include-symbols`

Comment: Have you tried fixing all these settings in the project which is referencing the nuget package?

https://urbanonsoftware.com/assets/images/posts/debugging/debugging_settings.png


Found this screenshot from here:

https://urbanonsoftware.com/debugging-external-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what happened other than perhaps it's visual studio caching symbols, but doing the following has allowed my other machine and a coworker's PC to step into our nuget package. I initially published the nuget package with this command `dotnet nuget push GenRepo.1.0.10.nupkg -s http://10.10.10.30/nuget`

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Pull nuget package source code onto coworker machine
3. Build and compile nuget package code and ensure the option to create .nupkg on build is selected
4. Open another Visual Studio instance with the other project that is referencing the nuget package
5. All of the sudden coworker can step into the nuget package

As I said, I don't fully understand what's happened here as I didn't set up a symbol server or anything of that nature.

**EDIT**

One thing to note, we had to move the file paths for the solution files on my coworkers computer to match mine before it worked